# How to check multiple cells intersection

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using the `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)` function in VBA excel.

I have multiple cell, where I want to know when these value have changed. For example if A1, B2, F4 and G13 cell is changed, I would like to do something. The easiest way is that:

```
 If Target.Address = Range("A1").Address Or Target.Address = Range("B2").Address .... Then
```

But It's very long. Is there any shorter way, to check it?

Comment: like `If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1,B2,F4,G13")) Is Nothing Then`???

Comment: Thanks! That was what I needed!